# How to join multiple column into one? Laravel

Tags: php, html, sql, laravel

This is my controller:

```
public function search(request $request)
{
    $request->flash();
    $search = $request->get('q');
    $vehicles = vehicle::where('make', 'LIKE', '%'.$search. '%')
                ->orWhere ( 'model', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%' )
                ->orWhere ( 'year', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%' )
                ->paginate(9);
    return view('user.vehicles.vehicles',compact('vehicles'));
}
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/vehicles/search', 'VehiclesController@search');
```

Laravel Blade

```
<form action="/vehicles/search" method="get">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 my-1">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="q" value="{{ old('q')}}" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search for brand, model, year, etc">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit"><span class="fa fa-search"></span></button>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<form>
```

**Problem**:

When I search for ex: `Toyota`, all Toyota in vehicle will show because of

```
where('make', 'LIKE', '%'.$search. '%')
```

But when I search for `Toyota Innova 2013`, there is no result.

What I want: when I search for `Toyota Innova 2013`, the code should show all the result from `make`, `model` and `year`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$vehicles = vehicle::where(function($query) use ($search) {
    $parts = explode(' ', $search);
    foreach ($parts as $part) {
        $query = $query->where('make', 'LIKE', '%'.$part. '%')
            ->orWhere ( 'model', 'LIKE', '%' . $part. '%' )
            ->orWhere ( 'year', 'LIKE', '%' . $part. '%' )
    }
})
```

I have not tested this however it should compare each word in the search query with each of the columns

Comment: what is the use of part here `foreach ($parts as $part) {
        $query = $query->where('make', 'LIKE', '%'.$search. '%')
            ->orWhere ( 'model', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%' )
            ->orWhere ( 'year', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%' )
    }` ?

Comment: Sorry forgot to change the $search to $part. This means that the query is looking for each word in the search term. I have updated my code. well picked up

Comment: `syntax error, unexpected 'return' (T_RETURN), expecting ',' or ')'`

Comment: Add a ")" after the where function. see my updated code

Comment: still no search found .. `vehicles/search?q=bmw`

Comment: @Kingbon Can you please show your code now and do a log of the query results?

Comment: `$vehicles = vehicle::where(function($query) use ($search) {
            $parts = explode(' ', $search);
            foreach ($parts as $part) {
                $query = $query->where('make', 'LIKE', '%'.$part. '%')
                    ->orWhere ( 'model', 'LIKE', '%' . $part. '%' )
                    ->orWhere ( 'year', 'LIKE', '%' . $part. '%' )
                    ->paginate(9);
            }
        });
        return view('user.vehicles.vehicles',compact('vehicles'));`

Comment: this what happen in search   `select
  *
from
  'vehicles'
where
 'make' LIKE "%acura%"
  or 'model' LIKE "%acura%"
  or 'year' LIKE "%acura%"
limit
  9 offset 0`

Comment: Can you please show the result in the DB for acura?

Comment: What happens when you run the raw MYSQL in your DB program?

Comment: @Kingbon. I am glad that you found a solutions. Can you please post the solution incase anyone in the future is trying solve the same problem

Answer (score 0):

You have to make three search buttons according to column in one form.

You are passing three parameters from controller using `$search`.

Try this in your model:

**First column**

```
 if ($request->make != null && $request->make != '') {
     $data->where('vehicle.make', $request->make);
 }
```

**Second column**

```
 if (isset($request->model) && $request->model != '') {
     $data = $data->where('vehicle.model', $request->model);
 }
```

**Third column**

```
 if (isset($request->year) && $request->year != '') {
     $data = $data->where('vehicle.year', $request->year);
 }
```

Comment: Since Builder's `where()` method is modifying the instance itself, re-assigning value to `$data` here is probably of no use.
[Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_where)

Answer (score 0):

i use db::raw and concat
[laravel doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-concat)

```
use DB;

public function search(request $request)
     {
      $request->flash();
      $search = $request->get('q');
      $vehicles = vehicle::where(\DB::raw("CONCAT_WS(' ', make, model, year)"), 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
      ->paginate(9);
      return view('user.vehicles.vehicles',compact('vehicles','vehicless'));
    }
```